# Как включить модули ES6 в node.js?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Можно ли через npm ?

```
import path from "path"; //error
var router = path.parse('new','cicik');

console.log(router.name);
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 1):

Node.js c 9той версии [поддерживает модули ES6 в экспериментальном режиме](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/esm.html). Для этого нужно запускать node с флагом --experimental-modules и скрипт должен иметь расширение mjs.
Например node --experimental-modules test.mjs